# How to make Taphost below actionbar (android)

Tags: android

I tried all the answers similar to that question on this website but still couldnt fix it. taphost is below the action bar and i wanna make it above the action bar. I have a custom action bar.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mediamer.metwally.saidkotb.activities.makalatActivity"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            </TabWidget>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my custom action bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
       >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:src="@drawable/homebutton"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:id="@+id/homeButton"
            />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            />
    <com.mediamer.metwally.saidkotb.helpers.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/TextColor"
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            />
            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/svZelal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:searchIcon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```